# javascript, loop string xml inside for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, string, loops

hey guys  I have trouble with loop string for xml inside for loop. I have tried this and the loop is not work

```
var data = [{"name": "Tom", age: "20"}, {"name": "Jerry", age: "20"}]

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var xmltext = '<Placemark>\n' + 
        '\t<name>' + data[i].name + '</name>\n' +
        '\t<age>' + data[i].age + '</age>\n' +
        '</Placemark>';
}

var filename = "file.xml";
var bb = new Blob([xmltext], {type: 'text/xml'});

document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(bb));
document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('download', filename);
```

the result I expected in xml

```
<Placemark>
  <name>Tom</name>
  <Age>20</Age>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
  <name>Jerry</name>
  <Age>20</Age>
</Placemark>
```

is there something i'm missing or i'm doing it wrong? I wish your help

Comment: What result are you currently getting?

Comment: You're overwriting `xmltext` each time through the loop. You need to add to it with `+=`.

Comment: @Barmar: Your comment is worthy of being an (the) answer.

Answer (score 0):

you create the on every iteration the xmltext var new. But you want to just declerate it once and add the String to it like this:

```
var data = [{"name": "Tom", age: "20"}, {"name": "Jerry", age: "20"}]
var xmltext = "";
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
xmltext = xmltext + '<Placemark>\n' + 
    '\t<name>' + data[i].name + '</name>\n' +
    '\t<age>' + data[i].age + '</age>\n' +
    '</Placemark>';
}
```